# how can skip a test in same class- selenium web driver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently working on **Selenium Webdriver** and using **Java**.. The test run in **Firefox 26.0**.. In **Eclipse** am using **TestNG** frame work..

- If I'm running test name **Test.java**. In that i have many filter section combination with the drop down values as well as date picker and multi select box shown in the image.

[image]

Based upon the filter section i have written code as follows:

```
Log.info("Clicking on Visualization dropdown");

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('visualizationId').style.display='block';");   
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId")));
select.selectByVisibleText("Week");
Thread.sleep(6000);

Log.info("Clicking on Period dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor1.executeScript("document.getElementById('periodId').style.display='block';");
Select select1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("periodId")));
select1.selectByVisibleText("Last 4 Weeks");
Thread.sleep(6000); 

Log.info("Clicking on Apply Filter button");
driver.findElement(By.id("kpiFilterSubmit")).click();// This is the one combination of filter section

//Filter selection-2

Log.info("Clicking on Visualization dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor3 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor3.executeScript("document.getElementById('visualizationId').style.display='block';");
Select select3 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId")));
select3.selectByVisibleText("ICC");
Thread.sleep(6000);

 Log.info("Clicking on Type dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor02 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor02.executeScript("document.getElementById('classificationId').style.display='block';");
Select select02 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("classificationId")));
select02.selectByVisibleText("Internal PRs");
Thread.sleep(6000);

Log.info("Clicking on Priority dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor5 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor5.executeScript("document.getElementById('priorityId').style.display='block';");
Select select5 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("priorityId")));
select5.deselectAll();
select5.selectByVisibleText("Not Urgent");
Thread.sleep(6000);

Log.info("Clicking on Apply Filter button");
driver.findElement(By.id("kpiFilterSubmit")).click();
Thread.sleep(6000);// Second combination of filter section.
```

For example, if some time i can't able to identify element or some other issue means usually the code will stopped and it is showing error. But in my case i want to skip that particular filter section and i need to move to the other combination of the filter section. please help me to make the code in better standard.. I'm learning java and selenium web driver..

Comment: Jugaad would be to use try catch for each section. Ideally you should handle each case which may throw error, i.e., use proper wait, check if element is present then only proceed on any action on it etc. On the other hand you may use framework like testNg to handle each of your test case.

Comment: There might be a much far better way of doing it: when you click 'Apply Filter', the page is possibly sending a URL request to the server, according to the values in the drop-down menus. So instead of choosing all these values and clicking 'Apply Filter', you might be able to simply build the URL string and navigate to it with your web-driver. If you provide the URL of the web-page that you are trying to automate, then I might be able to help you out with it.

Comment: I too Had the same problem but still waiting for the better solution...if you found the answer please let me know

Comment: Could you provide html code of this part of page, I have some ideas to improve your code, but need more details

Answer (score 0):

> in my case i want to skip that particular filter section and i need to
>   move to the other combination of the filter section
>   Blockquote

You can use 'verify' helper method.

Wiki: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#assertion-or-verification

For example,

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
if(verifyElementPresent(By.id("visualizationId")){
    executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('visualizationId').style.display='block';")   
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId")));
    select.selectByVisibleText("Week");
    Thread.sleep(6000);
}
...
        public boolean verifyElementPresent(By by) {
            try {
              driver.findElement(by);
              return true;
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
              return false;
            }
          }
```

btw, 
It is not a good decision to use `Thread.sleep(6000);`

You could face different problems.

So try to use waits. 
Wiki: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Your target is not clear - should only one successful combination used or you want run tests with all succeed combinations? I may suggest to use Data Provider. It provides input data for your tests. In your case it could be list of filters to use. This list will be manage in dependent @Test or in @BeforeTest. All failed combinations will be mark as failed and skipped as usual Tests.